Возможно ли реализовать такое на Mikrotik?
Собственно вопрос следующий, есть три домена (к примеру site.ru, site2.ru и site3.ru). Все три в DNS хотинг провайдера смотрят на один IP адрес (к примеру 88.88.88.88, который является внешним адресом роутера Mikrotik ax3). За роутером во внутренней сети есть три сервера с IP адресами 192.168.1.10, 192.168.1.11 и 192.168.1.12 соответственно. На каждом из данных серверов поднят WEB сервер и на каждом по одному сайту site.ru, site2.ru и site3.ru соответственно. Если возможность в такой конфигурации организовать доступ к каждому сайту из внешней сети?


Это, вероятно, нужно маркирование в L7-правилах... работать может и будет, но ме-е-едленно...

А какой тогда правильный вариант? Что в этой схеме не хватает?

Ну правильный (с моей точки зрения) вариант уже озвучил @eri в своём ответе. Микротик - это маршрутизатор. А всё, что выше (уровнем в модели) - это не для него задачи.

@Akina, спасибо понял

Лучший вариант это запустить 4ый сервер для разделки https и проектированием на нужный.
nginx proxy_pass
На микротике можно в контейнер, но это плохая практика.

Четвёртый конечно вариант, но хотелось бы штатными возможностями Mikrotik, если конечно это возможно.

Только костыли. Штатных нет

Это очень печально (

а чем плоха практира развернуть docker? Можно подробнее?

Памяти отожрет, ах памяти отожрет. Ну при 10 запросах в минуту работать будет нормально.
